# Error on compiling protobuf .pb.cc files with c++17 Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, protocol-buffers

###### What version of protobuf and what language are you using?

Version: main/v3.19.4
Language: C++

###### What operating system (Linux, Windows, ...) and version?

Windows

###### What runtime/compiler are you using (e.g., python version or gcc version):

Visual Studio 2019 MSVC C++17

I am trying to build an openEdr project that uses this library in Visual Studio 2019 with C++ Language runtime **ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)**
so once it compiles .pb.cc files, it generates lots of error 400+.

I can't go with the C++11 version because C++17 features are used in the project.

I am done with all the library and finally, these errors getting.

[image]

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: libcloud, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>annotations.pb.cc
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/stubs/status.h(97,15): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::util::status_internal::Status::error_message_': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::util::status_internal::Status'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xstring(4905): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/stubs/logging.h(100,15): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::message_': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xstring(4905): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h(1282,28): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::default_serialization_deterministic_': struct 'std::atomic<bool>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\atomic(2859): message : see declaration of 'std::atomic<bool>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(307,23): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::SerialArena::space_allocated_': struct 'std::atomic<unsigned __int64>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::SerialArena'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\atomic(2871): message : see declaration of 'std::atomic<unsigned __int64>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(412,29): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::alloc_policy_': class 'google::protobuf::internal::TaggedAllocationPolicyPtr' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(112): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::TaggedAllocationPolicyPtr'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(415,29): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::threads_': struct 'std::atomic<google::protobuf::internal::SerialArena *>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(415): message : see declaration of 'std::atomic<google::protobuf::internal::SerialArena *>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(416,29): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::hint_': struct 'std::atomic<google::protobuf::internal::SerialArena *>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(415): message : see declaration of 'std::atomic<google::protobuf::internal::SerialArena *>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arenastring.h(77,43): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::LazyString::inited_': struct 'std::atomic<const std::string *>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::LazyString'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arenastring.h(77): message : see declaration of 'std::atomic<const std::string *>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arenastring.h(323,26): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::tagged_ptr_': class 'google::protobuf::internal::TaggedPtr<std::string>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/arenastring.h(118): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::TaggedPtr<std::string>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/metadata_lite.h(261,15): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::LiteUnknownFieldSetter::buffer_': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::LiteUnknownFieldSetter'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xstring(4905): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/message_lite.h(445,30): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::MessageLite::_internal_metadata_': class 'google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadata' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::MessageLite'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/metadata_lite.h(62): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadata'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/implicit_weak_message.h(93,15): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::ImplicitWeakMessage::data_': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::ImplicitWeakMessage'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xstring(4905): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h(193,20): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::CachedSize::size_': struct 'std::atomic<int>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::CachedSize'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\atomic(2866): message : see declaration of 'std::atomic<int>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h(136,40): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::WrappedMutex::mu_': class 'google::protobuf::internal::CallOnceInitializedMutex<std::mutex>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::WrappedMutex'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h(136): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::CallOnceInitializedMutex<std::mutex>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.h(1627,25): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptor::LazyInitData::once': struct 'std::once_flag' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptor::LazyInitData'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xcall_once.h(21): message : see declaration of 'std::once_flag'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.h(2041,27): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::tables_': class 'std::unique_ptr<google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::Tables,std::default_delete<google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::Tables>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorPool'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.h(2041): message : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::Tables,std::default_delete<google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::Tables>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.h(2051,31): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::unused_import_track_files_': class 'std::map<std::string,bool,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,bool>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorPool'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.h(2051): message : see declaration of 'std::map<std::string,bool,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,bool>>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h(243,30): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::io::CopyingInputStreamAdaptor::buffer_': class 'std::unique_ptr<uint8_t [],std::default_delete<uint8_t []>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::io::CopyingInputStreamAdaptor'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h(243): message : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<uint8_t [],std::default_delete<uint8_t []>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h(334,30): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::io::CopyingOutputStreamAdaptor::buffer_': class 'std::unique_ptr<uint8_t [],std::default_delete<uint8_t []>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::io::CopyingOutputStreamAdaptor'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h(243): message : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<uint8_t [],std::default_delete<uint8_t []>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h(206,29): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::fields_': class 'std::vector<google::protobuf::UnknownField,std::allocator<google::protobuf::UnknownField>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h(206): message : see declaration of 'std::vector<google::protobuf::UnknownField,std::allocator<google::protobuf::UnknownField>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/extension_set.h(1070,26): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults::default_repeated_field_int32_t_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int32_t>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1045): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int32_t>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/extension_set.h(1071,26): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults::default_repeated_field_int64_t_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int64_t>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1047): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int64_t>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/extension_set.h(1072,27): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults::default_repeated_field_uint32_t_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<uint32_t>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1046): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<uint32_t>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/extension_set.h(1073,27): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults::default_repeated_field_uint64_t_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<uint64_t>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1048): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<uint64_t>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/extension_set.h(1074,25): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults::default_repeated_field_double_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<double>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1050): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<double>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/extension_set.h(1075,24): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults::default_repeated_field_float_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1049): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/extension_set.h(1076,23): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults::default_repeated_field_bool_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<bool>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPrimitiveDefaults'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1044): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<bool>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(48,76): warning C4251: 'TableStruct_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto::aux': union 'google::protobuf::internal::AuxiliaryParseTableField' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct 'TableStruct_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h(141): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::AuxiliaryParseTableField'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(488,93): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorSet::file_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorSet'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(470): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(873,49): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::_has_bits_': class 'google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/has_bits.h(83): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(875,58): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::dependency_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_ptr_field.h(1235): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(876,89): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::message_type_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::DescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(667): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::DescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(877,93): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::enum_type_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::EnumDescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(685): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::EnumDescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(878,96): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::service_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(703): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(879,94): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::extension_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::FieldDescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(721): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::FieldDescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(880,53): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::public_dependency_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int32_t>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1045): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int32_t>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(881,53): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::weak_dependency_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int32_t>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(1045): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int32_t>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1075,49): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto_ExtensionRange::_has_bits_': class 'google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto_ExtensionRange'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/has_bits.h(83): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1249,49): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto_ReservedRange::_has_bits_': class 'google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto_ReservedRange'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/has_bits.h(83): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1593,49): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto::_has_bits_': class 'google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/has_bits.h(83): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1595,94): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto::field_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::FieldDescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(721): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::FieldDescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1596,89): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto::nested_type_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::DescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(667): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::DescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1597,93): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto::enum_type_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::EnumDescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(685): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::EnumDescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1598,104): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto::extension_range_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::DescriptorProto_ExtensionRange>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1461): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::DescriptorProto_ExtensionRange>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1599,94): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto::extension_': class 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::FieldDescriptorProto>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(721): message : see declaration of 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::FieldDescriptorProto>'
1>C:\openedrBuild\openedrNew\openedr-release-2.5.1\openedr-release-2.5.1\edrav2\eprj\protobuf\include\google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h(1600,94): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::DescriptorProto::oneof_decl_': class
```

I don't understand how to resolve it. Please help me to resolve these issues.
I will be very thankful to you for a great community.

Thanks, community

Edit 1: Added Visual Studio 2019 Error image for your reference.

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors, (specifically [this warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4251?view=msvc-170)) and I doubt that they are related to the C++ version.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for the reply. I have added a Visual Studio 2019 Error image for your reference.  please have a look at it.

Comment: Your error screenshot obscures the source code. Paste code and errors as text instead. Even better, try to reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: I guess there is either something wrong with the code generation (not very likely) or something wrong with your configuration (more likely). The generated code does not seem to work with the protobuf library.

Comment: @molbdnilo Can you please help me out with this? I have built a protobuf using vcpkg.

Comment: Then I'm guessing that there is a conflict between that version of protobuf and the one that's included in openedr.

Comment: @molbdnilo ok, let me try to with the latest version of protobuf.